# Plotly 25th and 75th Percentile is different from Pandas and Numpy 25th and 75th Percentile

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, statistics, plotly

I am using plotly boxplot but I found that the Q1 and Q3 numbers are very different from the 25th Percentile and 75 Percentile numbers from pandas and numpy, which is what I wanted my plotly boxplot to show.

Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Percentile from Pandas describe function

```
DateTime                Mean            Median   25% Percentile   75% Percentile
254 2020-12-24 09:00:00 19479.529412    18155.0  17695.0          19259.0
```

Percentile from Numpy

```
DateTimeStarted              mean           median   percentile_25  percentile_75
254 2020-12-24 09:00:00     19479.529412    18155.0  17695.0        19259.0
```

[image: Plotly Percentile]

Comment: do you have nans in your data?

Comment: Yes. Is that why I am getting the difference? How does plotly, numpy and pandas treat nan differently?

Comment: May you check out whether the output of `np.nanpercentile()` agrees with Plotly?

Comment: Hi how can I do that? Sorry am still pretty new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html#r08bde0ebf37b-1

Notice there are multiple methods (9 at the moment of writing) of calculating the percentile in numpy, the default is 'linear'.

=================================================================

Now looking at the plotly documentation, unfortunately the method for calculating percentile can only be changed under the `plotly.graph_objects.Box()` function, but not the higher level `plotly.express`

Refer to this link:
https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Box.html

Scroll down you will see one of the parameters:

> "quartilemethod – Sets the method used to compute the sample’s Q1 and Q3
> quartiles. The “linear” method uses the 25th percentile for Q1 and 75th percentile for Q3 as computed using method #10 (listed on http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v14n3/langford.html). The “exclusive” method uses the median to divide the ordered dataset into two halves if the sample is odd, it does not include the median in either half - Q1 is then the median of the lower half and Q3 the median of the upper half. The “inclusive” method also uses the median to divide the ordered dataset into two halves but if the sample is odd, it includes the median in both halves - Q1 is then the median of the lower half and Q3 the median of the upper half."

Of course, the 'linear' method specified here can be different from the 'linear' method in numpy and pandas. The link provided in the plotly doc is dead so I have no idea what exact method they are using. There are only three options, 'exclusive' , 'inclusive' and 'linear'. So I suggest you play around with these three to see which one match the numpy default result.

In any case, the difference should be minimal and should only affects the "borderline" outliers.